# How to display bootstrap toggle switch as off/on?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

All bootstrap toggle switch docs show on/off examples.

http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/.

Currently `On` is displayed left and `Off` right.
How can I change their visual position so that `Off` is left and `On` is right?

```
<%= f.check_box :someday, :data => { size:'small', 'on-color'=>'danger'}, class: 'someclass' %>

<script>
  $("[class='someclass']").bootstrapSwitch();
</script>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want it off by default?

Comment: No @MarkoAvlijaš. I'm not looking to just change the `on-text`. I'm looking to reverse the functionality of on/off to off/on.

Comment: I really don't understand this. What I could grasp is that you want it to be in "off" state and  having text "Off" by default.  Not sure what else do you want. What do you mean by reverse the functionality?

Comment: @MarkoAvlijaš. Look at the doc. All the examples have on/off. How can you make it where "On" is displayed to the right?

Comment: You can trigger the toggle event on pageload or something.
` $("[class='someclass']").bootstrapToggle('on')`

If you want to change the layout you need to look at the css file.

Comment: Aha ok. I understand now. Honestly I wouldn't do it, seems like it requires digging into and changing their code. Not worth it just so `on` can be right instead of left.

Comment: Alright that's what I feared. Okay thanks for the help @MarkoAvlijaš :]

Comment: You are welcome :)

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com btw have you tried setting `direction: rtl;` css and/or `dir="rtl"` html attr (just a wild guess.)

Comment: Nah didn't work thanks for trying @mudasobwa